# implementation of Ternary Operator renders both conditions in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-operator

I am trying to implement conditional rendering in react using ternary operator, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Here's what I have below:

```
const [isDeleted, setIsDeleted] = useState(false);
```

I have a function which deletes users:

```
 const deleteUser = () => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/delete", []).then((resp) => {
      setIsDeleted(resp.data);
      isDeleted(true);
    });
  };
```

I am calling the `deleteUser` function onclick below, which changes `isDeleted` to true.

```
            <Box>
            <Button
              sx={{
                padding: "10px 20px",
              }}
              onClick={deleteUser}
            >
              Delete User
            </Button>
          </Box>
```

Below, want to use ternary operation here to render `successfully deleted` if isdeleted is true, and display `Hello User` if it isdeleted is false. What I have is just priniting it on my screen. I can't seem to get the right syntax.

```
             <Typography
                fontWeight="bold"
              >
                isDeleted? Successfully Deleted : Hello User
              </Typography>
```

Comment: `isDeleted(true);` will throw an error, you can't *call* `false`.

Comment: change condition to this : { isDeleted?  'Successfully Deleted'  : 'Hello User'}

Comment: @T.J.Crowder please can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @Didi - You have `const [isDeleted, setIsDeleted] = useState(false);`, then later you have `isDeleted(true);`. But `isDeleted` will be `false` (to start with), so that's like doing `false(true)`, which is an error. To *set* `isDeleted`, you use `setIsDeleted` as you do on the previous line.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the statement with `{}`

```
{ isDeleted ? <>Successfully Deleted</> : <>Hello User</>}
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing brackets

```
<Typography fontWeight="bold">
    {isDeleted? "Successfully Deleted" : "Hello User"}
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 <Typography fontWeight="bold">
     {isDeleted ? `Successfully Deleted` : `Hello User`}
  </Typography>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ternary is JavaScript expression. All such expressions [should be enclosed inside brackets](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions-as-children) `{}`:

```
<Typography fontWeight="bold">
  {isDeleted ? "Successfully Deleted" : "Hello User"}
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 1):

`isDeleted` is a property, you should use the method `setIsDeleted(resp.data);`